# how duplicates are getting eliminated while using subquery

Tags: sql, database

this may be a simple question but, i need someone to explain this. I'm trying to retrieve data from a table car_employee on the condition price_paid > 10000 (it is from another table: car_purchases) and i'm using the below query.

```
select eid, fname, lname, home_phone
from dbo.car_employee
where eid in (select eid from dbo.car_purchases where price_paid > 10000);
```

It is giving me correct answer but, when i execute the inner query alone it is giving me duplicate values of eid but, the whole query is not giving any duplicates. How the data is getting filtered there ?

PS: I have used JOIN as alternative but, there i'm getting duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates are not getting filtered out.  This is simply how `IN` works.  The `WHERE` clause cannot *increase* the number of rows (except in very exceptional circumstances in a small number of databases).

This is true whether the list is constants or a subquery.  So, these do the same thing:

```
where x in (1)
where x in (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

If you want the rows to multiply, use `join` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

Your outer query is coming from the car_employee table, so, unless a car_employee has multiple records for the same EID, they're going to show up 1 time (or 0)

The "where eid IN" is just limiting, not joining, so it cannot add records to the car_employee table-- or better put, you can get no more than 1 result per record in the car_employee table.

```
 select 1 where 1 in (1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
```

will result in a single row -- "1"